# Update state values with props change in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a modal component that should be called when setState changes but for some reason it is not updating. In the first file Im setting the following in render.

```
<ModalParcel showModal={this.state.showModal} parcelToConfirm={this.state.dataForParcelToConfirm} />
```

Within the Modal component constructor() I am setting the following.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log("Constructor for modal componenet called.")

    //this.renderRowForMain = this.renderRowForMain.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      show: this.props.showModal
    };

  }

render() {

    if(this.state.show == true){

        var content = 
        <View style={styles.modal}>
            <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.closeModal()}>
                    <Text>Close</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>;

    }else {

        var content = null;

    }

    return ( content );

  }
```

The problem is that the constructor() only gets called once on initial creation. I was under the impression that when I update the state to show the modal the constructor would be called again but this isn't happening.

I basically want to change the state to show the modal and then re-run render().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `constructor` will not get called when component re-rendered, it will get called only on initial rendering.

I think, there are two ways by which you can solve your issue:

**1.** Use `componentWillReceiveProps(){` lifecycle method it will get called whenever any change happens to props values, so you can update the Modal component `state` value showModal here, like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp){
   this.setState({
      show: nextProps.showModal
   });
}
```

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

**2.** Don't store the `props` value in `state` variable and directly use `this.props.showModel` in Model component, by this way whenever any change happens to props values, Modal component will take the updated values.

Comment: Thank you for the response, just tried it and it works great.